# Unsupported Operand Error generated from custom factorial function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

```
f = input("Enter the number to be squared : ")
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
print(factorial(f))
```

I am trying to get the factorial of the input number

When running the code I receive the following error:
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'`

Comment: The closing `)` if `print` is missing.

Comment: What error are you getting? Please post your error

Answer (score 1):

You have to typecast your input into `float` or `integer` for it to be accepted on your mathematical equation. You can even place that in a `while` loop together with the `try:` and `except ValueError:` to cover the error in entry or give messages when your user does not satisfy the type you want your `f` variable. You can read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) for more info.

```
f = int(input("Enter the number to be squared : "))
```

OR

```
f = float(input("Enter the number to be squared : "))
```

On your original code `f` would take any a string value even if the user inputs the number `2` for example. So when you call the function that solves your factorial, it will return an error, because of course, you cannot do factorial notation on a string.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem that I see is with your data types. You will need to convert `f` to either an integer or a float so that it can be used in the mathematical operations in your function. You may also want to include some exception handling in case the user enters something other than a number.

You can convert the type by using `int(f)` or `float(f)`

As another commenter mentioned, you are also missing a parenthesis at the end of `print(factorial(f)`.

If you make these changes your code should run.

Answer (score 0):

1. You forgot closing parenthesis ')' at the parenthesis end.
2. The data type of variable 'f' must be an integer and you are passing a string. As 'input' assigns string data type by default to the variable.

Make the following changes:

```
f = int(input("Enter the number to be squared : "))
print(factorial(f))
```

to lines 1 and the last line respectively.